# Drawback to catch-all exception (at highest program level, followed by re-raising, just to log before exiting?)

Tags: python, exception

I have a long-running program on a remote machine and want to be sure that (1) I have a record of any exception that causes it to terminate and (2) someone is notified if it terminates. Does anyone see drawbacks to the method I am using? (or have recommendations for a better one?)

I've read the Python docs and many exception-related posts here, and understand that blanket except clauses are usually a bad idea. Within subroutines and modules I always 
use except to handle specific expected exceptions, but it seems useful to have a "catch-all" except clause at the highest level of the program to ensure I can log the exception before the program exits.

What do you think?

```
import traceback
try:
    # main program code here
except BaseException:
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    msg = "Exiting program due to exception:" + tb
    LogToFile(msg)         # custom logging function
    SendAlertEmail(msg)    # warn admin that program terminated
    raise                  # program exits with the existing exception
```

Note that I was using BaseException instead of Exception because if someone at the terminal presses Ctrl-C, I *would* like to log that as the reason for exiting the program (and alert an admin that the program was exited). But I suppose I could also use:

```
except Exception, KeyboardInterrupt:
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no specific drawback, but there *is* an excellent alternative -- [sys.excepthook](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html?highlight=sys.excepthook#sys.excepthook).

In your specific version, consider using a bare `except:`, and `sys.exc_info()` to get the exception information; that will ensure you *do* catch everything -- even in the weird case where some module raises something *else* than an instance of a subclass of `BaseException`.  E.g.:

```
>>> class X: pass
... 
>>> raise X
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
__main__.X: <__main__.X instance at 0xc9ad0>
```

As you see, it *is* still possible to raise something a `except BaseException:` would not catch -- that's why bare-except `except:` still exists (specifically for very special uses such as yours!).

Whether you use the hook, or build your own, consider (perhaps depending on configuration flags or environment settings) *not* burdening the end-user with all the details (just as a neat touch of improved user experience!), just a meaningful summary (reassuring the user that all details of the problem have been recorded, etc, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and useful comments, and good point about not all module exceptions necessarily inheriting from BaseException. (p.s. I'm a brand new user so I don't seem to be able to upvote your answer yet)

Comment: @emdash, yep, you need I think 15 rep to upvote (but you can always _accept_ the answer that has most helped you -- after a while to see if others are coming, of course -- and get started on the rep earning threadmill, since you get some rep for accepts, too, though the accepted answerer gets more).

Answer (score 4):

Consider what happens if the exception is due to lack of diskspace. If the logging is written to the same partition

```
LogToFile(msg)
```

will raise an exception, an so no email is sent either. A simple try/except around each will avoid that problem

```
tb = traceback.format_exc()
msg = "Exiting program due to exception:" + tb
try:
    LogToFile(msg)         # custom logging function
except:
    pass
try:
    SendAlertEmail(msg)    # warn admin that program terminated
except:
    pass
raise                  # program exits with the existing exception
```

Comment: Thanks, good point. And if I wanted to have a record of every exception, I could additionally email/save any exceptions that occur in the process of saving/emailing the first exceptions.

Comment: @fmark, I've had a bunch of driveby downvotes lately. Maybe they are from the same person. Perhaps they didn't like the naked `except:`. No way of knowing...

Answer (score 0):

"I've read the Python docs and many exception-related posts here, and understand that blanket except clauses are usually a bad idea."

The rationale for that is that you might be expecting three kinds of exception then wind up swallowing the fourth kind that you never considered was a possibility. A handler that does an unconditional re-raise eliminates this concern -- you *will* be seeing unexpected exceptions -- so it's a perfectly cromulent exception to the general rule.